# Junk data when using fread

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io

I'm trying to use fread to get lines of data from a text file. The first thing my program does is open the text file, and determines the byte offset of the beginning of each line.

The byte offset of line 1 is 0, and is stared in `offset[1]`. The byte offset of line 2 might be 45 bytes, and that will be stored in `offset[2]`, and so forth. The byte offset of the `EOF` is stored in `array[lastline + 1]`

In a loop, I'm trying to use these statements to print what I want:

```
fseek(fptr, ptr[line], SEEK_SET);
fread(str, sizeof(char),  (  (ptr[line + 1] - ptr[line]) - 2) / sizeof(char) , fptr);
printf("%03ld %03ld %s\n", line, ptr[line + 1 ] - ptr[line], str);
```

my fread statement uses `((ptr[line + 1] - ptr[line]) - 2) / sizeof(char)` for the number of elements to print. I have several concerns here.

1. I'm using -2 to try and account for the newline and carriage return.
   My professor said that I have the two extra bytes/line because of
   the newline and carriage return. Should I be trying to take care of
   them this way? Does it make my program less portable?
2. My program will print a range of lines or a single line upon user
   request. When I print more than one line, the second line's output
   is really mangled.

   Printing lines 2 to 4 ...
   LINE: 2
   002 005 123
   003 011 123456789¼ü|♥
   004 007 123456789¼ü|♥

The first column is line number, the second is the BYTE LENGTH OF THAT LINE, not the byte offset. When I print only one line, it's sometimes mangled, but not always.

```
Printing line 1...
001 008 123456☻
```

I'm thinking that I'm either not using fread properly, or I'm doing something really bizarre with the way I'm reading from the text file and storing it into the temp string before printing. What seems to be the problem?

EDIT:

OK, so my loop for using fread was already assigning the return to some variable. I didn't know what to do with it until just now. Following the suggestions in the comments, I'm using

```
count = fread(stuff);
str[count] = '\0';
```

This seems to have fixed it.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `fseek` and `fread`, which is almost guaranteed to be a serious programming error.

Comment: Where are you verifying that ptr[line+1]-ptr[line] won't blow the size of your str buffer?

Comment: @jthill I allocated str with BUFSIZ number of characters. I think it's 512 characters, should be big enough?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably forgetting about the null terminator

`char s[] = "ABC"; // {'A', 'B', 'C', '\0'}`

`s[3] = '\0';`

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* value, and your code is trying to assign it into a `char`. I recommend using `s[3] = '\0'` or `s[3] = 0` instead.

Comment: Am I doing this in the few lines of code I posted? I'm not seeing where I could be doing that in just these few lines of code..

Comment: That's your mistake ;) You *should* set the terminating `'\0'` at some point in your code, but you don't.

Comment: @R.. `'\0'` makes it clear (for the reader) that it is a `char`, not an `int`.

Comment: `'\0'` is an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `str[something] = 0` at some point, before using `str`. If you are dealing with a text file it will most certainly not contain a 0 terminator.

That something could be the number of characters returned by `fread`.

---

Side note: `sizeof(char)` looks ridiculous since it's 1 by definition.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is good code style, because it reads more naturally. The reader knows that is is the size. If he/she reads 1, it's not very clear why it is 1.

Comment: @leemes `*Diplomacy on*` I guess it's a matter of taste :-)

Comment: Yea, I thought it was important to be clear, and I don't know about the conventions for encoding characters, but what if on some system, it's TWO?

Comment: @user1357836: The C standard *requires* that `sizeof(char) == 1`, even if `char` is something like 16 bits.

Comment: @leemes sizeof(X) is pointless when you *know* the underlying size of X.

Comment: So in theory, 'something' would be the the number of characters returned by fread. Ideally, this number would be equal to the number of characters in any given line in my text file. Why would I want str[something] to be 0?

Comment: @Cicada A good code style is *never* pointless. But as cnicutar said, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I think `sizeof(char)` is very bad style, and a *code smell*. That is, when I see it, I assume the author of the code did not know that `sizeof(char)` is 1, and inspect the code very carefully for (often dangerous) bugs.